# Unable to set mod_rewrite LogLevel in config

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to set LogLevel to trace8 in my Apache server config file.  I've entered:

```
LogLevel trace8
```

but when I try to save the file I get

```
Error: Apache settings has invalid value
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to trace the messages coming out of mod_rewrite.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set it like this:

```
LogLevel rewrite:trace8
```

Ref: [mod_rewrite: Logging](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging)

Comment: Thanks.  I also found that trace1 to trace8 was added to LogLevel  in Apache 2.4 and my hosting provider still has me at 2.2. They're upgrading now, and then if I do it the right way it will hopefully work.    Thanks!